# How to prioritize the order of css with css coming from the node module?

Tags: css, node-modules, primeng, primeng-datatable

I use primeNg table in my html page and when I am responsive I would like to keep the header of my grid.

however the table "`p-datatable-thead`" is automatically set to "`display-none`" with node

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 40em)
<style>
.p-datatable.p-datatable-responsive .p-datatable-tfoot>tr>td, .p-datatable.p- 
 datatable-responsive .p-datatable-thead>tr>th {
 display: none!important;
}
```

this css comes directly from the node primeng module:

node_modules > primeng > ressources > components > table > table.css

I tried to cancel this css with my own stylesheet :

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
  .gridAccount.p-datatable.p-datatable-responsive .p-datatable-tfoot>tr>td, .p- 
  datatable.p-datatable-responsive .p-datatable-thead>tr>th {
     display: table-cell !important;
   }
 }
```

but my css goes after the css of the component from node_modules.

[image]

How to make my own css go in front of the node_modules css ?